# Preset address in Hyperlink field on SPS2013 newform.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, url, hyperlink

Is it possible to preset a specific URL on the Hyperlink field within newform.aspx page part of SPS2013 List.

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Comment: Can you provide more information such as which link on newform also screenshots would be helpfull

Comment: @AnkitkumarMalde, I want the Hyperlink field which is available to be added to SPS2013 list, to have a preset URL, such that while user create a new item, the Hyperlink field has the value already set and user doesn't need to provide any information in the Hyperlink column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a bit of JavaScript on the page.

Edit the newform.aspx page and add a Script Editor web part with this code (note the use of jQuery hosted by Google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var internalNameOfUrlField = "hyperLinkFieldName";
    var urlToSet = "http://www.google.com";

    $("[id^='" + internalNameOfUrlField + "'][id$='UrlFieldUrl']").val(urlToSet);
</script>
```

Change the values of the `internalNameOfUrlField` and `urlToSet` variables to what ever is appropriate for your case.

Comment: Tried for fieldname: Link on my SPS Online  and SPS2013, no change.

`code`
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var internalNameOfUrlField = "Link";
    var urlToSet = "http://www.google.com";

    $("[id^='" + internalNameOfUrlField + "'][id$='UrlFieldUrl']").val(urlToSet);
</script>
`code`

Comment: Are you sure the internal name of your column is `Link`? Press F12 in your web browser and check the console for any JavaScript errors.

Comment: well it worked, now is their an option to hide the columns. Reason I want the value to be set on the hyperlink under newform.aspx, but don't want the user to see, as they may try to change the value. Later when they view on dispform.aspx it will show the hyperlink value. Hope that makes sense, if not, let me know to explain in detail.

Comment: Alrite, got the way to hide the column using Jscript.
Thanks @Submits for the solution on preset address.